# Finding a subarray within a large integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, find

I'd like to calculate the high watermark of a task stack on my embedded CPU using C++.
Unfortunately the OS does not offer such a method.

The task stack itself is an array of ints. An unsed stack contains 0xCDCDCDCD as a value. Since 0xCDCDCDCD might be a valid value, I'd like to find the first occurence of the termination sequence repeated 4 times.

So I'm searching an int (sub) array within a large int array.
Since i have to suspend the task this method should be very efficient.

I tried the very naive way.

```
#define STACK_DEFAULT_VALUE 0xCDCDCDCD          ///< marking for an empty stack element
#define N_EMPTY_SUCCESSORS  4                   ///< Min number of succeedeing stack elements before we assume we found the high watermark

int Get_Task_Stack_High_Watermark(const int* const pStack, const int stack_size)
{
    int res = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<stack_size;i++)
    {
        if(*(pStack[i] != STACK_DEFAULT_VALUE))
        {
            //this part of the stack was allready in use
            continue;
        }

        bool res = true;

        //we found a stack mark => check if the next stack elements are unused as well
        for(int j = i; j<i+N_EMPTY_SUCCESSORS; j++)
        {
            if(j>= stack_size)
            {
                //we reached the end of the stsck!
                return 0;
            }

            if(*(pStack[j] != STACK_DEFAULT_VALUE))
            {
                //this is not the end of the stack
                res = false;
            }

        }

        if(res)
        {
            //this is the end of the (used) stack
            //calculate remaining stack size
            res = stack_size - i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return res;

}
```

However I'd like to know if there's a faster way to do this?

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: So does this all boil down to finding `n` consecutive occurrences of a given value?

Comment: it boils down to finding the first occurrence n consecutive occurrences :)

Comment: You could simply short-circuit the test by first finding `0xCDCDCDCDCD`, and then seeing if the item 4 slots down is also `0xCDCDCDCDCD`.  If it isn't, then you can skip that entire block, since there is no need for further testing.

Comment: do you mean by using std::find()?

Comment: Visualize with a bigger example.  What if you wanted to see if 100 consecutive entries were `0xCDCDCDCD`?  You would find the first one, and then immediately look 100 slots down to see if that item is also `0xCDCDCDCDCD`.  If it isn't, you can skip that entire block, since it can't be one that satisfies the criteria, i.e. you go to the next block after the 100th one you tested for.  With your approach, you would be wasting time checking block i, i+1, i+2, i+3, etc. later to find out that block i + 99 (for example) is not `0xCDCDCDCD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a counter to keep track of the number of special values in a row:

```
#define STACK_DEFAULT_VALUE 0xCDCDCDCD          ///< marking for an empty stack element
#define N_EMPTY_SUCCESSORS  4                   ///< Min number of succeedeing stack elements before we assume we found the high watermark

int Get_Task_Stack_High_Watermark(const int* const pStack, const int stack_size)
{
    int consecutiveEmpties = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i < stack_size; i++)
    {
        if(pStack[i] == STACK_DEFAULT_VALUE)
        {
            consecutiveEmpties++;

            if(consecutiveEmpties == N_EMPTY_SUCCESSORS)
            {
                return i - 4;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            consecutiveEmpties = 0;
        }
    }

    return stack_size;
}
```

Or if you really don't care about readability:

```
int Get_Task_Stack_High_Watermark_2(const int* const pStack, const int stack_size)
{
    int consecutiveEmpties = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < stack_size; i++)
    {
        if ((consecutiveEmpties = (consecutiveEmpties + 1) * (pStack[i] == STACK_DEFAULT_VALUE)) == N_EMPTY_SUCCESSORS)
        {
            return i - 4;
        }
    }

    return stack_size;
}
```

The second version is a bit faster (visual studio with release mode)